# ajax response not working after android apk build from build.phonegap.com server

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I have called ajax into my cordova phonegap android project.ajax response come from external url. When build apk from eclipse,it working fine but after upload the project zip to build.phonegap.com server and generate apk.this apk not give ajax response. I have add ' and
    ' into my config.xml page where ajax response come from http://example.com/subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to set an appropriate Content-Security-Policy meta tag in the head of your index.html.  It is likely that your local Cordova/Phonegap version with Eclipse is older than the one on PhoneGap Build, and doesn't require this.

Cordova 5 and newer require the Content-Security-Policy meta tag, and by default don't allow external Ajax requests.

You will need to configure your connect-src clause to allow * (all servers) or list out those you want to connect to.

Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://myserver.mydomain.com">
```

Changing myserver.mydomain.com for * (for all servers) or a space separated list of URLs if you want to limit where your app can go get data from.

There's a [blog post here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/) that helps explain this in detail.

Comment: after add this into header tag of index.html.Still not working.

Comment: Thanks - if you could accept my answer that would be great.